# Onboarding/Walkthrough AutoLoad

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and xcode and I was wondering if somebody can help me out with an issue I face for a while... 
How can I make a storyboard load automatically, instead of pressing a button to start?

A good example is here:
https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough

In this example here, and others found online, there is always a button to be pressed, but in the app I am developing, I want to load the first screen automatically, and have a skip/continue button.

This is the code for the button:

```
@IBAction func playWalkthrough() {
    // Get view controllers and build the walkthrough

    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Walkthrough", bundle: nil)
    let walkthrough = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walk") as! BWWalkthroughViewController
    let page_zero = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walk0") as! UIViewController
    let page_one = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walk1") as! UIViewController
    let page_two = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walk2")as! UIViewController
    let page_three = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walk3") as! UIViewController

    // Attach the pages to the master
    walkthrough.delegate = self
    walkthrough.addViewController(page_one)
    walkthrough.addViewController(page_two)
    walkthrough.addViewController(page_three)
    walkthrough.addViewController(page_zero)

    self.presentViewController(walkthrough, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]
[image]

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Click on your viewController in the Storyboard, go to the property inspector and set `is Initial View Controller` to true.

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't load the other screens, from the Walkthrough storyboard. Also tried to load the app with the Walkthrough storyboard as a main interface, but I have the same result. So, I have a Walkthrough View Controller ( which holds the button CLOSE and the UIPageControl elements (the dots) and another 3 Page View Controllers (the screens). The first screen  is trigger on top of the Walkthrough View Controller only by the action button (Start Walkthrough) from the Main Storyboard. Is there any way to load it automatically on the View Controller, without that button?

Comment: @Rob what do you mean by it doesn't load the other screens? Why should it load screens that aren't displayed? You should set up your storyboard so that your viewcontrollers are all included somehow. Maybe you should read a storyboard tutorial..?

Comment: the walkthrough is working fine, my only issue is that i don't know how to remove the 'start walkthrough' button and make the screens load automatically in the main view controller. Can you please have a look at my second image?